# Get current category of channel entry corresponding to current URL

Tags: conditionals, structure, url, categories

I have a channel, products, with a URL structure like this:

```
/product/description/categoryA
/product/description/item-in-categoryA
/product/description/item-in-categoryA2
/product/description/item-in-categoryA3
/product/description/categoryB
/product/description/item-in-categoryB
/product/description/item-in-categoryB2
/product/description/item-in-categoryB3
```

When I am on, for example, `/product/description/item-in-categoryB3`, I want to indicate that `categoryB` is the current category. However, I cannot find a way to do this. I have tried {if active}, which never returns true whether I am inside channel categories or channel entries (using version 2.5x). I have tried inspecting the URL segment but I cannot rely on this when I am on an item's page as the category does not appear in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're successfully showing the entry's data then you should be able to call the categories from within the channel:entries tag loop with the [categories loop](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories).

```
{categories}{category_name}{/categories}
```

Is that working for you?

Comment: Yes, that does work. Thanks. I'm now working on passing this around with Preload replace.